# Java reading a .txt file and sorting using a substring

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, queue, substring

So I have written out the code which opens and reads a .txt file then prints the contents. Now I've done that I want to sort the data into three separate linked lists according to the first character in each bit of data which will be F, T or P. An example of some data F12, F43, T31, P64, P17, T23 etc. So these should look like so after being sorted...

Bay F: F12, F43

Bay T: T31, T23

Bay P: P64, P17

Any help with this is appreciated, and I mean any help. Below is my code so far.

EDIT:-
Ok I've now amended the changes but I'm still getting the same print. So Before the changes I got this print T16,T17,F99,F14,P34,P88,T63,F58,P02,P76,F77,T99,P14,P24,T88,F63,F53,T02 and after the changes I still got T16,T17,F99,F14,P34,P88,T63,F58,P02,P76,F77,T99,P14,P24,T88,F63,F53,T02 so I'm not sure what's going wrong?

```
package stackandqueue;


import java.util.*;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StackAndQueue 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
// Create an three empty queues of station bays objects
LinkedList<String> bayoneQueue;
bayoneQueue = new LinkedList<String>();

LinkedList<String> baytwoQueue;
baytwoQueue = new LinkedList<String>();

LinkedList<String> baythreeQueue;
baythreeQueue = new LinkedList<String>();


// Open and read text file
String inputFileName = "PodData4.txt";
FileReader fileReader = null;

// Create the FileReader object
try {
    fileReader = new FileReader("PodData4.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    String str;
    while((str = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        System.out.println(str + "\n");
        switch (str.charAt(0)) 
        {
    case 'F':
    bayoneQueue.add(str);
    break;
    case 'T':
    baytwoQueue.add(str);
    break;
    case 'P':
    baythreeQueue.add(str);
    break;
    default: // in case of invalid input!
        }
    }
                br.close();

    }catch(IOException ex)
      {
//handle exception;
      }

finally
{
    fileReader.close();

// close resources
}

// Close the input



}
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the order matters within each individual list, so you could just iterate through the file, check the first letter of each item, append the item to the respective linked list, then continue with the next item. Could possibly do this within the "while((str = br.readLine()) != null)". Also, I just noticed that your fileReader.close() is in a totally new try block (with a catch, no less). It should be in the finally block instead (where you mentioned "close resources").

Comment: Ok so I've now amended the changes but I'm still getting the same print. So Before the changes I got this print T16,T17,F99,F14,P34,P88,T63,F58,P02,P76,F77,T99,P14,P24,T88,F63,F53,T02 and after the changes I got T16,T17,F99,F14,P34,P88,T63,F58,P02,P76,F77,T99,P14,P24,T88,F63,F53,T02 so I'm not sure what's going wrong?

Comment: You are just printing the line that you are reading, and not the linked lists, so the prints won't change. You need to change the printing to be for the linked lists instead. The problem is at `System.out.println(str + "\n")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your `try` to a "try-with-resources" which will automatically close the `BufferedReader`. Then the line will be read in from the file and split around each comma into the `strings` array. The `switch` statement will then add each string into their respective `LinkedList`. I also moved your `fileReader.close()` into the `finally` block.

```
// Open and read text file
String inputFileName = "PodData2.txt";
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("PodData2.txt");

// Create the FileReader object
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);)
{    
    String[] strings = br.readLine().split(",");
    for (String str : strings)
    {
        switch (str.charAt(0))
        {
            case 'F':
                bayoneQueue.add(str);
                break;
            case 'T':
                baytwoQueue.add(str);
                break;
            case 'P':
                baythreeQueue.add(str);
                break;
            default:
                // In-case of invalid input
        }
    }
} 
catch(IOException ex)
{
    //handle exception;
}
finally
{
    fileReader.close();
}
System.out.println("Bay F: " + bayoneQueue.toString());
System.out.println("Bay T: " + baytwoQueue.toString());
System.out.println("Bay P: " + baythreeQueue.toString());
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the code. It runs successfully but doe's not print out anything.

Comment: @DParker You should be able to `System.out.println(bayoneQueue.toString);` and do the same for the others.

Comment: @DParker Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Really helped me out alot :)

Comment: @DParker Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess all you need is a switch statement inside the while loop

```
while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(str + "\n");
    switch (str.charAt(0)) {
    case 'F':
        bayoneQueue.add(str);
        break;
    case 'T':
        baytwoQueue.add(str);
        break;
    case 'P':
        baythreeQueue.add(str);
        break;
    default: // in case of invalid input!
    }
}
```

Also consider moving the `fileReader.close()` statement to inside the finally clause as it is a "closing resource" operation as mentioned in your comments.

Comment: Ok so I've now amended the changes but I'm still getting the same print. So Before the changes I got this print T16,T17,F99,F14,P34,P88,T63,F58,P02,P76,F77,T99,P14,P24,T88,F63,F53,T02 and after the changes I got T16,T17,F99,F14,P34,P88,T63,F58,P02,P76,F77,T99,P14,P24,T88,F63,F53,T02 so I'm not sure what's going wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your help :)